# Is there a way to sync all devices on a wifi network?

Tags: networking

I have a desktop running Linux Mint, a laptop running PureOS, and an Android phone all connected to the same wifi network.  I was wondering if there were some way to have like a "public" folder that any of the devices can dump files into or download from.  That way whenever I'm on any device, if I download files that I know I'll eventually want access to on other devices I can always download them into this public folder and all other devices receive it, immediately or the next time they connect to the network.

If there isn't a software solution, is there some sort of hardware that can do this?

Comment: What total size of data are you thinking of? Dropbox or equivalent would seem to be the obvious solution here for a relatively small amount.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) is designed exactly for this: it can sync folders across multiple devices, with intermittent connectivity. Folders don’t have to be shared across all devices, or even bi-directionally (*e.g.* to back your phone up). It can be configured to only sync within a given network, or over the Internet. It’s supported on a wide range of devices.